# Refresh the page just once

Tags: html

refreshes the page every 21 seconds. I need it to happen just once. How can this be done?

```html
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="21;url=index.html">
</head>
```

Comment: If you want refresh just once you don't need to use meta. You can do that with jquery and php. But why you want refresh your page? Please explain that maybe can do better than refresh page.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a `meta` refresh for this.

Set a timer in JavaScript that executes a callback function after 2100 milliseconds:

```
setTimeout(function(){ location.reload(); }, 2100);
```

Comment: thank you but i need this function to work one time  . how can make that ?

Comment: [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) runs the callback function you supply one time after the delay has expired. This does exactly what you are asking for.